# Cordova 10.0.0 and Ionic 5.6 version is running on web, but not generate apk

Tags: java, android, angular, cordova, ionic5

Full log when generating the apk,
Java version is jdk8
android platform version is 8.1.0 using android@8.1.0

```
The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone@17.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@17.1.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk@17.0.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@20.2.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@17.4.3
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut@17.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@19.0.7
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@16.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@21.4.3
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection@17.0.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@18.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base@17.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api@17.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop@17.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@20.2.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@19.3.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@16.+
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@17.4.3
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl@17.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.onesignal:OneSignal@4.8.5
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@17.0.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-config@19.1.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager@17.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop@19.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype@17.0.0

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
uild.gradle file.
```

I want to make a successfull debugable apk.